# Is there a named quantification of the "nonlinearity" of a probability distribution?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, terminology

Let $(X_n)_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of square-integrable real-valued random variables $X_n$ with cumulative distribution function $F_{X_n}$; and for simplicity, assume that for each $n$, the pre-image of $\frac{1}{2}$ under $F_{X_n}$ is a single point $p_n$ at which $F_{X_n}$ is continuous. Let $S_{X_n}$ denote the nonparametric skew of $X_n$, that is,
$$ S_{X_n} = \frac{\mathbb{E}[X_n] - p_n}{\mathrm{s.d.}[X_n]}. $$
According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonparametric_skew), $S_{X_n}$ lies between $-1$ and $1$.

> Is it necessarily the case that $S_{X_n} \to 1$ if and only if $F_{X_n}(\mathbb{E}[X_n]) \to 1$?
>
> If not, is there a name for the quantity
> $$ \nu_X := \big|\tfrac{1}{2} - F_X(\mathbb{E}[X])\big| $$
> associated to a random variable $X$, or at least a name for some quantity for which convergence to the least theoretical upper bound is equivalent to convergence of $\nu_X$ to $\frac{1}{2}$?

(It would seem a bit disconcerting if the answer to both questions is *no*.)